# Selenium webdriver switcing windows in Firefox 59.0.2 and Selenium 3.11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While switching between windows using Selenium web driver 3.11 and Firefox 59.0.2 
I am getting the below exception 
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Missing 'handle' parameter

PS: The issue is while running tests using RemoteWebDriver.

Any Ideas or Workarounds ?

Comment: The question doesn't contains enough information.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This is a selenium bug affecting Firefox only through Grid. Switching between tabs or windows will fail because it's not passing the correct parameters. I haven't found a workaround yet in my own projects, beyond avoiding switching windows or tabs.

Checkout out this [ticket logged on the SeleniumHQ github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5064).

Comment: Thanks Kmcgon for the  link to the Selenium ticket.